# Excel VBA editor view settings

Tags: excel, vba, editor

Somehow I changed the view in my VBA editor and all the code and userform open at the bottom of the window.  Normally this would be to the right of the Project Explorer/Properties windows.  I have docked, undocked, hide, unhide and reset everything I could and I have yet to find a way to put the code window back in the right position.  The Project Explorer/Properties window goes completely across with no open space to the right.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to get them into the state you describe, but undocking them all and then re-docking them manually seems to work just fine, assuming you "drop" them in the right place and right order. You say you have already tried that? There is no "other way" unless maybe you completely uninstall Office and re-install it. "Drop" the 2nd one on the title bar of the first one.

Comment: I prefer to adopt the old VB6 layout: code window on left side and Project Explorer & Properties windows on right side. Immediate window goes on bottom. This task is a trial and error work.

Comment: In trying to work out how to do this I have made mine like yours and can't work out how to reverse it either.  If you find a solution please let me know as it is highly annoying.

Comment: I found it. Type regedit in the search window and run the Registry Editor app.  From there go to HKEY_Current_User/Software/Microsoft/VBA/7.1/Common.  Click on common and it will show all the settings.  I simply renamed the DOCK settings so as not to lose them and restarted Excel.  The editor was back to normal.  I reopened the Registry Editor and found it had created a new DOCK folder and I still had the renamed folder.  I then deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Type regedit in the search window and run the Registry Editor app.  From there go to HKEY_Current_User/Software/Microsoft/VBA/7.1/Common.  Click on common and it will show all the settings.  I simply renamed the DOCK settings so as not to lose them and restarted Excel.  The editor was back to normal.  I reopened the Registry Editor and found it had created a new DOCK setting file  and I still had the renamed setting file.  I then deleted it.