# Any idea, how to remove or reinstal VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, editor

My VBA Editor for office is superzoomed to the left corner of menu panel. I can acces settings with shortcuts, but didn´t find way how to repair it.

I reinstall Office but it didn´t help. I also try to delete settings through registry with no effect.

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lWip.gif)]

Comment: Possibly helpful? [Excel VBA editor view settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668459/excel-vba-editor-view-settings)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I already tried to fix it in registry editor, and it didn´t work.

Comment: Try these shortcut keys one at a time on a computer with only one screen ideally a laptop.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-for-accessibility-021bcb62-45c8-e4ef-1e4f-41b8c1fc87fd

Comment: Is it just in Excel, or other Office programs too?

Comment: All programs in Office 21 Pro